# "Oserror cannot identify image file" can't load file from folder

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras

I'm doing a project that trains a model that can classify plankton images. However, when I am doing my code and run it, it says that my image is in a folder that it cannot identify. First, I thought it have some with problem with the file name. I changed all jpg to png. But nothing changed. Every image on that folder works fine. 
I am not using PIL, so I am still trying to figure out what is my problem, but nothing changed.The folder exists, and the image works normally.
Here is my code:

```
import sys
import os
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from keras import optimizers
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dropout, Flatten, Dense, Activation
from keras.layers.convolutional import Convolution2D, MaxPooling2D
from keras import callbacks


train_data_path = '/media/sexybeam/Suzuya/Study/Group-Project/Python/train et test/data/train'
validation_data_path = '/media/sexybeam/Suzuya/Study/Group-Project/Python/train et test/data/validation'

"""
Parameters
"""
img_width, img_height = 128, 128
batch_size = 16
samples_per_epoch = 1000
validation_steps = 300
nb_filters1 = 32
nb_filters2 = 64
conv1_size = 3
conv2_size = 2
pool_size = 2
classes_num = 3 ## change this number with number of plankton folder you have
lr = 0.0004
epochs = 20

model = Sequential()
model.add(Convolution2D(nb_filters1, conv1_size, conv1_size, border_mode ="same", input_shape=(img_width, img_height, 3)))
model.add(Activation("relu"))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(pool_size, pool_size)))

model.add(Convolution2D(nb_filters2, conv2_size, conv2_size, border_mode ="same"))
model.add(Activation("relu"))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(pool_size, pool_size), dim_ordering='th'))

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(256))
model.add(Activation("relu"))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(classes_num, activation='softmax'))

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer=optimizers.RMSprop(lr=lr),
              metrics=['accuracy'])
print(model.summary())

train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1. / 255)
test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1. / 255)

train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    train_data_path,
    target_size=(img_height, img_width),
    batch_size=batch_size,
    class_mode='categorical')

validation_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    validation_data_path,
    target_size=(img_height, img_width),
    batch_size=batch_size,
    class_mode='categorical')

"""
Tensorboard log
"""
log_dir = '/media/sexybeam/Suzuya/Study/Group-Project/Python/train et test/data/validation'
tb_cb = callbacks.TensorBoard(log_dir=log_dir, histogram_freq=1)
cbks = [tb_cb]

model.fit_generator(
    train_generator,
    steps_per_epoch=samples_per_epoch,
    epochs=epochs,
    validation_data=validation_generator,
    callbacks=cbks,
    validation_steps=validation_steps)

target_dir = '/media/sexybeam/Suzuya/Study/Group-Project/Python/train et test/models'
if not os.path.exists(target_dir):
  os.mkdir(target_dir)
model.save('/media/sexybeam/Suzuya/Study/Group-Project/Python/train et test/models/model.h5')
model.save_weights('/media/sexybeam/Suzuya/Study/Group-Project/Python/train et test/models/weights.h5')
```

My error trace

```
Using TensorFlow backend.
/media/sexybeam/Suzuya/Study/Group-Project/Python/train et test/train.py:77: UserWarning: Update your `Conv2D` call to the Keras 2 API: `Conv2D(32, (3, 3), input_shape=(128, 128,..., padding="same")`
  model.add(Convolution2D(nb_filters1, conv1_size, conv1_size, border_mode ="same", input_shape=(img_width, img_height, 3)))
/media/sexybeam/Suzuya/Study/Group-Project/Python/train et test/train.py:81: UserWarning: Update your `Conv2D` call to the Keras 2 API: `Conv2D(64, (2, 2), padding="same")`
  model.add(Convolution2D(nb_filters2, conv2_size, conv2_size, border_mode ="same"))
/media/sexybeam/Suzuya/Study/Group-Project/Python/train et test/train.py:83: UserWarning: Update your `MaxPooling2D` call to the Keras 2 API: `MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), data_format="channels_first")`
  model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(pool_size, pool_size), dim_ordering='th'))
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
conv2d_1 (Conv2D)            (None, 128, 128, 32)      896       
_________________________________________________________________
activation_1 (Activation)    (None, 128, 128, 32)      0         
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_1 (MaxPooling2 (None, 64, 64, 32)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_2 (Conv2D)            (None, 64, 64, 64)        8256      
_________________________________________________________________
activation_2 (Activation)    (None, 64, 64, 64)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_2 (MaxPooling2 (None, 64, 32, 32)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
flatten_1 (Flatten)          (None, 65536)             0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 256)               16777472  
_________________________________________________________________
activation_3 (Activation)    (None, 256)               0         
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_1 (Dropout)          (None, 256)               0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_2 (Dense)              (None, 3)                 771       
=================================================================
Total params: 16,787,395
Trainable params: 16,787,395
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
None
Found 6309 images belonging to 9 classes.
Found 891 images belonging to 9 classes.
Epoch 1/20
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/media/sexybeam/Suzuya/Study/Group-Project/Python/train et test/train.py", line 124, in <module>
    validation_steps=validation_steps)
  File "/home/sexybeam/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/legacy/interfaces.py", line 91, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/sexybeam/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1418, in fit_generator
    initial_epoch=initial_epoch)
  File "/home/sexybeam/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/training_generator.py", line 181, in fit_generator
    generator_output = next(output_generator)
  File "/home/sexybeam/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/utils/data_utils.py", line 709, in get
    six.reraise(*sys.exc_info())
  File "/home/sexybeam/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/six.py", line 693, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/home/sexybeam/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/utils/data_utils.py", line 685, in get
    inputs = self.queue.get(block=True).get()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 670, in get
    raise self._value
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 119, in worker
    result = (True, func(*args, **kwds))
  File "/home/sexybeam/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/utils/data_utils.py", line 626, in next_sample
    return six.next(_SHARED_SEQUENCES[uid])
  File "/home/sexybeam/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras_preprocessing/image/iterator.py", line 100, in __next__
    return self.next(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/sexybeam/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras_preprocessing/image/iterator.py", line 112, in next
    return self._get_batches_of_transformed_samples(index_array)
  File "/home/sexybeam/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras_preprocessing/image/iterator.py", line 226, in _get_batches_of_transformed_samples
    interpolation=self.interpolation)
  File "/home/sexybeam/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras_preprocessing/image/utils.py", line 104, in load_img
    img = pil_image.open(path)
  File "/home/sexybeam/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 2687, in open
    % (filename if filename else fp))
OSError: cannot identify image file '/media/sexybeam/Suzuya/Study/Group-Project/Python/train et test/data/train/amoeba5/IFCB1_2009_0_5167.jpg'
```

Comment: Can you post an example image? The error you describe suggests the files are malformed in some way.

Comment: Where exactly does the error popup? Please post the full error trace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your code and images. I had the same problem. The Issue is because of Keras **ImageDataGenerator** . if you use tensorflow cpu version it will work. but tensorflow-gpu will not work. if you want to save your time just forget about ImageDataGenerator and read images yourself.I don't remember what was the cause of this exactly.

scikit-image is a good package for working with images. you can read files like this:

```
from skimage.io import imread
from skimage.transform import resize
from skimage import img_as_float

#place holder for images
train_Images = numpy.zeros((sample_counts, height, width, channels))

for index,file in enumerate(ListOfFileNames):
    img = io.imread(file)
    #In case you want to resize images use the line blow
    img = resize(img, (height,width,channels), mode='reflect', anti_aliasing=True)
    train_Images[index] = img_as_float(img)
```